# Angular 2 Route Resolving Multiple Nested Observables

Tags: angular, routes, observable, resolve

I have an observable that has nested observables when subscribed too.

It stems from an issue where an api is called multiple times within a for loop to get the final output.

Somewhat more specifically, I first call the api for a widget, then I call the api to return an array of foo which I add to the widget object. Finally I loop through the foo array and retrieve foo.id, which is used to get bar. Bar is then added to the foo[x] element.

When I resolve widget in the router, widget's attributes are there, but the foo array is returned as an observable. I want to subscribe to foo before the route is resolved, and then loop through foo and subscribe to the bar in each foo element.

```
let routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'landing-page',
  component: LandingPageComponent,
  resolve: {
    widget: WidgetResolve,
    foo: FooResolve(widget),
    bar: BarResolve(foo)
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of returning nested observables, I used flatMap and forkJoin to allow the multiple api calls to resolve in one subscribe. The answer was based on a post for [Combining multiple Http streams with Observables in Angular 2](http://blog.danieleghidoli.it/2016/10/22/http-rxjs-observables-angular/)

```
getWidget(id) {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    this.service.getWidget(id),
    this.getFoo(id)
    ).map(res => {
      res[0].foo = res[1];
      return res[0];
    });
}


getFoo(id): Observable<any[]> {
  return this.service.getFoo().flatMap(fooArr => {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      fooArr.map((foo: any) => {
        return this.service.getBar(foo.id, id)
        .map((barArr: any[]) => {
          foo.bar = barArr;
          return foo;
        });
      })
      );
  });
}
```